# Unable to check the checkbox using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to check the checkbox using Selenium. This is the element of the checkbox.

```
<div class="ams-item-text ng-binding" ng-bind-html="amssh.create_label(item)" ng-click="toggle_check_node(item)" role="button" tabindex="0">all contract signed</div>
```

I'm directly copying the x-path of this element and wrote the below code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="advancedcontents"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]').click()
```

But it won't never click the check box that I wanted, but click the check box way below, which is with this:

```
<div class="ams-item-text ng-binding" ng-bind-html="amssh.create_label(item)" ng-click="toggle_check_node(item)" role="button" tabindex="0">future</div>
```

What could be the issues? I try the checkbox element, or the text element (also clickable) but both doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on dynamic element induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_element_located`() and following `xpath` option.

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ams-item-text ng-binding' and text()='all contract signed']"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(.,'all contract signed')]")).click()
```

**Note** : Add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply! I tried but I get the following error: ```NameError: name 'driver' is not defined```

Comment: should be browser in your case check above solution

Comment: Hi... So sometimes the code (not just the above code, but in general when I try to find element) works but when I try again a few times, it stops working. Do you know why?

Comment: I get an error message that says ```Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='daterangepicker_start']"}``` but the code was working well previously.

Comment: This is due to synchronization use web driver wait and allow page to load elements and then perform action on them

Comment: So is it better to always use  wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20) than do it without it?

Comment: Yes use it to avoid synchronization issues

Answer (score -1):

"ams-item-text ng-binding"browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="advancedcontents"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]').click()